# How much time does it take for the naive T Cell to get activated?

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology, immunology, immune-system

Suppose a naive T cell comes in contact with an APC. How much time does it take for the T Cell to get activated and within how much time does the T cell move away from the APC due to incompatibility in their receptor structure? What is the probability that there will be activation of a naive T cell by an APC (I mean to ask that how many T cells should come in contact with APC before a T cell gets activated, some number like say 1 out of every 1000 t cell gets activated by an APC at a particular time)?
 Any resource you can provide that gives a quantitative value of the interaction of T cell with APC, please do if possible.

Comment: Do you have any way to access Wiley Online articles? http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1016/j.febslet.2010.10.010/abstract